# Django Editing Native Register Form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-registration

In **register.html** template if I put

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

to use native register form it works. But it is very ugly. So I use it as

```
{{ form.username}}
{{ form.password1}}
```

But sometimes when an error occurs, I need to check if register form has any errors [example names]

```
{% if form.any_error %}
```

And show the message styled

```
{{ form.errormessage}} or {{ form.errorlist.values}}
```

How to achive this in Django with native form and what are the native form variables let us to do this?

Comment: You need to revisit django docs, especially [Rendering form error messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Comment: @vishes_shell This page doesn't give you native form's variable names. And *{% if form.subject.errors %}* is not working for native form.

Comment: Ok, but django docs is where you find everything You just need to search it [Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms). You can easy access `errors` attribute in `form` object.

Comment: @vishes_shell OK thank you very much. It worked for me! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look at [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)
You can add classes and attributes to your Form fields which gives you a lot of control over the Form styling.

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% load widget_tweaks %}
    {% csrf_token %}
<span>1. Title: {{ form.title|add_class:"titleCSS" }}</span>

{% if form.errors %}
            <span> {{ form.errors|add_class:"errorCSS" }} </span>
{% endif %}
</form>
```

Or As mentioned before you can use Crispy Forms they work fine and a lot of sites are using it but you have to work into the Crispy Forms package. 
With Widget Tweaks you can simply add CSS as you would do it in HTML.

Comment: OK Thank you very much. It solved the problem for me. 

Comment: I still don't get 100% what you wanted to achieve, but im glad I could help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in rendering Django forms in elegant and DRY way, you can check [Django Crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) third party app. It is designed to render forms easily using components from many different popular frontend frameworks (Bootstrap, Uni-form, Foundation).

It uses the correct widgets for all your form field types, and also manages validation errors, displaying errors with the correct markup and style.

Comment: OK, I will check it 